# Improvements on maintaining global application wide config object

Tags: javascript, typescript, single-page-application

The application which I am working on has multiple `products`. Product-specific config will help to avoid `if-else`. Also, I want to ensure that the config keys are maintained across product-specific config. This is achieved by using `interface` so that developer should not miss the `key` while adding it to a product.

What I am looking for is some suggestions on these below points  -

1. While this object could grow & become heavy in size, I also want to make sure that this class will `dynamically` import object based on the current `product-name` ( `product1 | product2`), etc. (So that overall performance can be improved.)
2. Better way to write the `ProductConfigService` class if any.
3. OR another approach this can be done efficiently ( leveraging TS)

Kindly suggest.

```js
interface PRODUCT_CONFIG {
    API_KEY: string,
    AGE: number,
    TEXT: string

}

const product1: PRODUCT_CONFIG = {
    API_KEY: "SOME_VALUE",
    AGE: 10,
    TEXT: "SOME_VALUE"
}


const product2: PRODUCT_CONFIG = {
    API_KEY: "SOME_VALUE"
    AGE: 12,
    TEXT: "SOME_VALUE"
}


class ProductConfigService {

    private product: PRODUCT_CONFIG;
    

    constructor(private accessKey:string) {
      this.product = product2; // should be dynamic based on the current selected application. This is hard-coded to product2.
    }

    getConfig(): string {
      //@ts-ignore
      return this.product[this.accessKey];
    }

}

// consumer.

let product = new ProductConfigService('AGE');

console.log(product.getConfig());
```

Comment: Why is it `product2` that is stored in `this.product` and not `product1` or an other object ? Are you looking for non empty `AGE` property because of `ProductConfigService('AGE')` ?

Comment: my bad. Basically, the product is dynamically assigned. The object holds relevant information if applicable to a product, if not it would be empty. But still, the key exists as a code is common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an abstract class that would be inherited to match every application needs.

---

There would be a `PRODUCT_CONFIG` by default, that could be also extended.

In the following code, `getConfig()` returns the correct type of value depending on the configured key.

---

warning : The annoying thing is that the user of `ProductConfigService` have to specify the name of the `key` used for the configuration. I don't know how to extract it from the parameter itself.

---

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-kChA8SWDpIiT8jLJ5Nrxr7fSdDF6UAEzwg1QGZIITVLTFQDYLgAHdQG8HlUSKSx4mYE0zXNPcsCIMgVErd0mEYM9rDpNsAEYLAwpMhnUQknx0ecDGMcxQAAckQWgnTkAA1atpFIZjhnLNwLBIgAGASghCcILFY9jSC4ni+IExsfjSFUOF-Cwt1HCjJxTGjy30IxTGktiOO43BeP4wT3FAEjf3E3RJIiFjTLk8zLIcujKxtatpL4fI2is40wDQ0LwHEccsDGRBSGYQjVJ-DhYFpSCYIXel235Lsew3ZjXD4lYATytxmIAuKVNAOoC2Swk1NgTFuUy6pBQuQj8gyLhMQyfIBSqjJYDKgiKrU+AUug8REuXLK12aPLDMY5jCrmhjTFK1qKr60basS+AGp5KbmsGtqOq6nqAU2o7hsmsa0smvlOxm3KKyrXBFqK56fNey7zzSPqMFpNSMD2pqBW+yx2s67reoLDBBtQsLQqAA)

---

```
// ---------- ABSTRACT CLASS DECLARATION

interface PRODUCT_CONFIG {
    API_KEY: string;
    AGE: number;
    TEXT: string;
}

abstract class AProductConfigService<T extends PRODUCT_CONFIG, U extends keyof T> {
    protected product: T;

    protected accessKey: keyof T;
    
    constructor(accessKey: keyof T, product: T) {
      this.accessKey = accessKey
      this.product = product;
    }

    public getConfig(): T[U] {
      return this.product[this.accessKey] as T[U];
    }
}

// ---------- CLASS IMPLEMENTATION

interface EXTENDED_PRODUCT_CONFIG extends PRODUCT_CONFIG {
    // additionnal keys ...
    ANIMAL: string;
}

class ProductConfigService<U extends keyof EXTENDED_PRODUCT_CONFIG> extends AProductConfigService<EXTENDED_PRODUCT_CONFIG, U> {
    constructor(accessKey: U) {
      super(accessKey, product2);
    }

    // ... new methods
}

// ---------- PRODUCTS DEFINITION

const product1: PRODUCT_CONFIG = {
    API_KEY: 'SOME_VALUE',
    AGE: 10,
    TEXT: 'SOME_VALUE',
}

const product2: EXTENDED_PRODUCT_CONFIG = {
    API_KEY: 'SOME_VALUE',
    AGE: 12,
    TEXT: 'SOME_VALUE',
    ANIMAL: 'fox',
}

// -------------- PRODUCT USE

const productA = new ProductConfigService<'AGE'>('AGE');

const valA = productA.getConfig();

console.log(valA);

const productB = new ProductConfigService<'API_KEY'>('API_KEY');

const valB = productB.getConfig();

console.log(valB);

const productC = new ProductConfigService<'ANIMAL'>('ANIMAL');

const valC = productC.getConfig();

console.log(valC);

// ----------------
```